# Including the switch "-hls_flags temp_files" while encoding to HLS does nothing

Tags: ubuntu, ffmpeg, http-live-streaming

I'm trying to disable access to video segment files while they are still being converted. This is to stop my web-page from loading the unfinished segments.

One solution that appeals to me is using the '-hls_flags temp_files' option that (according to the docs) initiates segments with the name 'filename.tmp', and renames them only once the segment is complete. This is opposed to the standard ffmpeg behaviour where unfinished segments have the same name as the completed ones.

Problem is I can't get '-hls_flags temp_files' to do anything. Converting a video with:

```
ffmpeg -i aerial.mov -g 60 -keyint_min 60 -sc_threshold 0 -f HLF -hls_time 2 -hls_list_size 0 -hls_flags temp_file aerial.m3u8
```

produces the exact same output as running the same command line without '-hls_flags temp_file'. Does anyone have experience using 'temp_file'?

**EDIT:** Issue was solved by getting a static git build of ffmpeg, instead of the latest (4.1.1) release build I had, as pointed out by user Gyan:

> Micro version of release should be ignored. git master is branched off for minor and major bumps. Minor upgrades only have security fixes for the most part. Get a static git build. Get one from the left column at [johnvansickle.com/ffmpeg](https://johnvansickle.com/ffmpeg)

Comment: Check your build is >26 Dec 2018. A bug was recently fixed.

Comment: I'm currently running version 4.1.1 which was released 2019-02-09.

Comment: Micro version of release should be ignored. git master is branched off for minor and major bumps. Minor upgrades only have security fixes for the most part. Get a static git build.

Comment: 4.1.1 is currently the latest stable release, or do you mean something else by "static git build"?

Comment: Get one from the left column at https://johnvansickle.com/ffmpeg/

Comment: Chirst almighty, it works. Using the static build 'temp_files' has the expected behaviour. Thank you for the tip!